# D3 v5: multiline chart, not able to get multiple lines to draw

Tags: d3.js

Thank you for any help you can offer in advance, I am new to D3 and having a hard time following the multiline chart examples I've seen online. I have data that looks like:

```
country,year,average
United States,1970,51
United States,1971,50
United States,1972,54
United States,1973,56
United States,1974,53
United States,1975,57
United States,1976,60
Brazil,1970,23
Brazil,1971,25
Brazil,1972,24
Brazil,1973,21
Brazil,1974,25
Brazil,1975,26
Brazil,1976,24
```

for multiple countries and I would like to make a line for each of them.

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 150, left: 70},
width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

 var w = width + margin.left + margin.right;
 var h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") // this appends a new SVG element to body
    .attr("width", w) // set the width 
    .attr("height", h) // set the height
    .append("g") 
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// x scale will handle time
 var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);

// y scale will handle energy consumption values
 var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height,0]);

// Define X and Y AXIS
 var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);
 var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale); 

 function rowConverter(data) {
      return {
           country : data.country, 
           year : +data.year,
           average : +data.average // the + operator parses strings into numbers
      };
}

// line generator function
 var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.average); })

d3.csv("EvenMore.csv", rowConverter).then(function(data) {

     var countries = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) { return d.country; })
        .entries(data); 

     console.log(countries);

     yScale.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.average; } )]); 
     xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; } )); 

    // Draw xAxis
     svg.append("g") // add a new svg group element
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");

    // Draw yAxis
     svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");


    svg.selectAll("path")
         .data(countries)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) { 
             return line(d.values); 
        });

});
```

I do not know what these errors mean, Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "….33333333333334LNaN,114.27777777…":

[image: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "….33333333333334LNaN,114.27777777…"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

You're not using the band scale correctly. A band scale is not a quantitative scale and therefore does not have an upper and lower bounds. Instead, every value of the domain needs to be specified:

> The first element in domain will be mapped to the first band, the
>   second domain value to the second band, and so on. Domain values are
>   stored internally in a map from stringified value to index; the
>   resulting index is then used to determine the band ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band-scales))

This explains your error, you've specified two values to the domain, the first year and the last year. We can see that the domain is only these two values a few ways, when looking at the scale (a band scale's axis by default includes all ticks, but even here we see the spacing is really odd if 1970 and 1976 are the start and end values):

[image]

The error message also helps in finding the error: if the first coordinate's x value was NaN the message would read `"Expected Number, "MNan,1234..."` when examining the path `d` attribute (especially without any curve applied), we can see the x value of every coordinate except the first and last are NaN.

**The solution**

You need to provide all values in the domain to the scale. We can get all values with:

```
xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.year; }))
```

The scale will weed out duplicates when setting the domain.

```js
var margin = {top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 150, left: 70},
width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

 var w = width + margin.left + margin.right;
 var h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") // this appends a new SVG element to body
    .attr("width", w) // set the width 
    .attr("height", h) // set the height
    .append("g") 
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// x scale will handle time
 var xScale = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);

// y scale will handle energy consumption values
 var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height,0]);

// Define X and Y AXIS
 var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(5);
 var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale); 

 function rowConverter(data) {
      return {
           country : data.country, 
           year : +data.year,
           average : +data.average // the + operator parses strings into numbers
      };
}

// line generator function
 var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.average); })

var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre").remove().text())


    data = data.map(rowConverter);

     var countries = d3.nest()
        .key(function (d) { return d.country; })
        .entries(data); 

     yScale.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.average; } )]); 
     xScale.domain(countries[0].values.map(function(d) { return d.year; })); 

    // Draw xAxis
     svg.append("g") // add a new svg group element
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");

    // Draw yAxis
     svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".25em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");


    svg.selectAll(null)
        .data(countries)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
             return line(d.values); 
        });
```

```css
.line {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
    stroke:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre>country,year,average
United States,1970,51
United States,1971,50
United States,1972,54
United States,1973,56
United States,1974,53
United States,1975,57
United States,1976,60
Brazil,1970,23
Brazil,1971,25
Brazil,1972,24
Brazil,1973,21
Brazil,1974,25
Brazil,1975,26
Brazil,1976,24</pre>
```

Comment: wow! thank you this is really helpful, there is now lines being drawn (yay!!)  but interestingly there are only 4 lines being drawn but there are actually 6 countries for which I have data. Here is what the output looks like now: https://imgur.com/wTrgxY8. Any thoughts on this? I really appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, this is expected behavior. You use `selectAll("path")` to create the lines, but there are already two paths existing in the axes - so the first two series' data are bound to these lines and the rest entered (enter creates an element where one doesn't already exist for every item in the data array). You can change the select all statement so it creates an empty selection: `selectAll(null)` or since you class the lines and may want to update them: `selectAll(".line")`. I took the 1st option in my snippet above (along with a few other changes required to parse the CSV from an HTML element)